# when i am running my application i get the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-commons-logging

The program extracts data from salesforce and writes it to a text file.

Please help me in understanding the reason for error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
    at com.sforce.soap.partner.SforceServiceLocator.<init>(SforceServiceLocator.java:16)
    at com.ncr.common.dataaccess.UserAuthentication.nscLogin(UserAuthentication.java:171)
    at com.ncr.common.dataaccess.UserAuthentication.getNscLogin(UserAuthentication.java:122)
    at com.ncr.extract.lms.NSCPartnerContactExtractLMS.startExtract(NSCPartnerContactExtractLMS.java:403)
    at com.ncr.extract.lms.NSCPartnerContactExtractLMS.main(NSCPartnerContactExtractLMS.java:85)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException))
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:370)
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler.<clinit>(BasicHandler.java:43)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:374)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: post your relevant code where you get an error

Answer (score 2):

You don't really provided so much information about your code, and it is so hard to say something from this stacktrace. It seems that there is an issue with the log4j. Have you seen [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245401/getting-exception-in-initializing-log4j-files). Also make sure that the log4j lib is included on your buildpath.

Comment: yes i have seen that post. i have added the library files to the class path of eclipse. but the error is still persisting.

Comment: As "Maxim Shoustin" said without pasting the affected code it is hard to say something, even guess. :)

Comment: i am using the eclipse 3.2.1 and i had added the debug logs to find out where the exception arises. Execption comes after the object creation of SforceServiceLocator. Please help.

Comment: Post the code instead of describing the issue. We can't help you if we can't see where the problem actually is.

Comment: Actually, since this exception occurs in apache-commons-logging, which is open source, what we really need to know first of all is which version of apache-commons-logging you are using!